# context.SaveChanges() not updating data in SqlServer database

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

When I call `context.SaveChanges()` to update a specific product, the update is not registered in the database. I do not get any runtime error either. All I notice is that my product catalog is not updated. I still see the same values. When I run the debugger I notice that the connection state of the database is closed.

This is the class implementing the context.SaveChanges()

```
namespace SportsStore.Domain.Concrete
{
   public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository
   {
       private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

       public IQueryable<Product> Products
       {
           get { return context.Products; }
       }

       public void SaveProduct(Product product)
       {
           if (product.ProductID == 0)
           {
               context.Products.Add(product);
           }

           context.SaveChanges();
       }
   }
 }

namespace SportsStore.Domain.Concrete
{
   public  class EFDbContext : DbContext
   {
     public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
   }
}

namespace SportsStore.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Product
    {

      [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
      public int ProductID { get; set; }

      public string Name { get; set; }

      [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
      public string Description { get; set; }

      public string Category { get; set; }

      public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `EFProductRepository` class, prior to calling the `context.SaveChanges()` method in the `SaveProduct` method, you can use one of the following approaches to persist changes to the database.

```
public void SaveProduct(Product product)
{
    if (product.ProductID == 0)
    {
       context.Products.Add(product);
    }
    //One approach to persist changes to database
    //var productInDB = context.Products.Single(x => x.ProductID ==product.ProductID);
    //context.Entry(productInDB).CurrentValues.SetValues(product);
    //context.SaveChanges();

    //Alternate Approach
    if (product.ProductID != 0)
    {
       context.Entry(product).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```